# How to automize creating variables?

Tags: python, list, function, variables

I have this code:

```
lst = [name_1, name_2, name_3, name_4, name_5, name_6, name_7]

for i in lst:   
    i = class.function(argument)
```

I would like to use the names in the list as variable names and in that way construct new variables, letting the machine do the hard work. But instead, I get this:
NameError: name 'name_1' is not defined.
What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible?

Comment: Dynamic variables are considered a very bad coding practice.  You really never want to use them.

Comment: You might thing that this makes your code more readable, or at least less repetitive. But the contortions you need to go through to make it work make your code far *less* readable. Use a `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont konw if I get your question. Do you want to know how to assign variable names dynamically? This is one solution, use python "exec()"

generally this is how we define a variable：

```
a=3
```

in this code we know the variable name when we write the code. But what if we dont know its name before the script run? We could use exec

```
var_name = ["a","b","c"]
var_value = [3,4,5]
for name,value in zip(var_name,var_value):
   exec("%s=%d" % (name,value))
print a,b,c
```

output:`3,4,5`

Comment: Yep, wanted to know how to assign variables dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a dictionary:

```
dict1 = {"name_1" : object here, "name_2" : object here}
```

So when you want to use that variable:

```
dict1["name_1"].someFunction(...)
```

Comment: This is the officialy blessed OneTrueWay.